# embed code twitter on Tinymce 4

Tags: extjs, twitter, tinymce, embed, tinymce-4

I am adding a plugin which insert twitter embed code. the problem is that I can see the tweet on the editor but not in the source code and preview. And I can't save it. I saw in forum that I have to add 'http:' to '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' and put it before , unfortunately, it's not working. This is the code I put:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('twitter', function(editor, url) {
    editor.on('init', function (args) {
        editor_id = args.target.id;

    });
    editor.addButton('twitter', {
        text: 'Twitter',
        icon: false,

        onclick: function () {

            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Twitter Embed',

                body: [
                    {   type: 'textbox',
                        size: 40,
                        height: '100px',
                        name: 'twitter',
                        label: 'twitter'
                    }
                ],
                onsubmit: function(e) {

                    var embedCode = e.data.twitter;
                    var script = embedCode.match(/<script.*<\/script>/)[0];

                    var scriptSrc = script.match(/".*\.js/)[0].split("\"")[1];
                    console.log(script);

                    var sc = document.createElement("script");

                    sc.setAttribute("src", "https:"+scriptSrc);
                    sc.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

                    var iframe = document.getElementById(editor_id + "_ifr");

                    var iframeHead = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                    var iframeBody = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

                    embedCode1 = embedCode.replace('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js','https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');

                    iframeBody.appendChild(sc);

                    editor.insertContent(embedCode1);

                    iframeHead.appendChild(sc);

                    // setTimeout(function() {
                    //     iframe.contentWindow.twttr.widgets.load();
                    // }, 1000)
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is that solved?

Comment: No, I have searched but didn't find the solution. So, I didn't insert this plugin to the editor.

Comment: is there any other solution you used?

Comment: I use now medium editor but I code my own functionnalities so I can use it without bug with extjs